# what is the meaning of "pro-rate"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

What does "pro-rate" in following sentence mean?

> We **pro-rate** our prices if you join after a session has started

does it mean that they reduce the price if I want to enroll after a session has been started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Pro-rate* means they calculate a price discount ***pro rata***, i.e. in proportion to the total cost.

So yes, they will reduce the price if you enroll after the start - the discount will be proportional to the amount of session that you've missed.

> **Pro rata**
>
> *adj.*: proportional.
>
> *"as the pound has fallen costs have risen on a pro rata basis"*
>
> *adv.*: proportionally.
>
> *"their fees will rise pro rata with salaries"*

<sup>Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/pro-rata).</sup>

It's interesting to note that the Oxford English Dictionary categorises the term *prorate* as belonging to the lexicon of American English (indeed this very question has been labelled with the 'american-english' tag), however The Free Dictionary and the Cambridge Dictionary attribute it to both that and its British counterpart. My experience tallies with the latter: it's very common to hear this term in Britain in a corporate environment.

Answer (score 1):

According to *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003), the verb *prorate* has two meanings in English—one transitive and one intransitive:

> **prorate** *vt* (1860) **:** to divide, distribute, or assess proportionately **~** *vi* **:** to make a pro rata distribution [where *pro rata* means "proportionately according to an exactly calculable figure (as share or liability)"]

<sup>[[Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prorate) has a similar treatment of *prorate*.]</sup>

In your example, the word is being used transitively, but the prices will be assessed—or more precisely, reduced—by the exactly calculable figure of how many sessions (as a percentage of the total number offered) a later arrival has missed prior to enrolling. So the two dictionary meanings are really much closer in sense than you might suppose by looking at them.

Comment: As a trainee accountant, donkey's years ago, I learned to use *pro-rata* as a transitive verb. e.g. *Pro-rata the cost between the departments based on headcount*. Presumably we should have been saying *pro-rate the costs...*But I guess you could say *Distribute the costs pro-rata to headcount*.

Comment: @WS2: I wouldn't be surprised if the verb _prorate_ were primarily a creature of U.S. English. I have encountered it occasionally in business/commercial settings (especially in past-tense form)—whereas I don't recall ever having met with _pro-rata_ functioning as a verb. Unfortunately, the coinage dates that MW gives are often extremely deceptive: It may find one or two occurrences from many years ago and record that date even though significant, continuous usage may have arisen much more recently.

Comment: @SvenYargs - Is that not to say that whilst anyone can mangle a language, it takes a sure-nuff American (and the dictionary they rode on) to whup the tar out'n it?  +0.967 (_pro rata_) for incisively perceptive affront to US lexicography.  ;-)

Comment: @Rob_Ster: The ability to mangle a language may be what makes us human—more so even than having opposable thumbs.